# On local server only, I get "window.gtag" is not a function" with checking "typeof window !== 'undefined'". Is it necessary to add another check?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics-4

In my react app, I am sending custom events data with functions that look like:

```
export const cityClickEvent = cityClicked => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    window.gtag("event", `click ${cityClicked} button`);
    }
 };
```

When I push to my production server, it seems to be firing events properly, but on my local version, I get the error:

```
 window.gtag is not a function
```

One solution I found was adding a check of:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.gtag === "function")
```

But I don't see anyone else doing that.  Is there a danger of adding this check or is it necessary for local servers?

Comment: I feel like it's good to check it, at least I've myself done it. Do you know any other way to check if analytics have loaded yet? If so, not a better way that that.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to add the check.

It's also ok to add the gtag.js lib to your local/lowers.

If you add it to the local and don't want to send events to your production GA4 property, it's a good practice to create a new GA4 property and use it exclusively in lowers and locals, which implies adding a piece of conditional logic to check if the env is prod and set your gtag config accordingly.

That said, the best practice is using GTM instead of directly calling gtag for these things, but if you're just having a few gtag calls through the codebase, then it's probably not worth it.